# How to find out all installed fonts on user machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to get the name of all installed fonts on user machine using HTML, javascript?

One way is to use classid, but i would like to know any other way round to do this?

Comment: You can't get the machine to *tell* you the fonts, but you could probably check for fonts by trying specific fonts on a block of text and detecting size changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect

Comment: this will tell me whether the specified font exists on user system or not. But my requirement is to know the name of all fonts existing on user sys.

Comment: in what situation it may not be enough?

Comment: Rakesh - there is no way other than trial and error. You cannot query for a list of fonts. You can only try a set of them and see if they work or not. This answer is the best one.

Comment: @Diodeus: By using classid i can get all fonts name. May be you are trying to say apart from classid method this is the best one. [ but definitely not acceptable one ]

Comment: I've never seen a classid in HTML for fonts. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Check this javascript library

https://github.com/gabriel/font-detect-js/

U can get the name of all installed fonts on user machine.

Comment: It should be noted that IE 11 does *NOT* list the fonts, it only shows Times New Roman. - and yes, this is with Adobe Flash properly installed.