# Is it possible to get vector font representation from local fonts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, fonts

Is there any way to get vector representation for user-provided font? I mean, if a user has some non-standard font installed on his system, I am able to [detect that font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228223/how-to-find-out-all-installed-fonts-on-user-machine), I can draw it to off-screen canvas and get raster font representation.

I searched for a long time, but couldn't find any way to get vector representation for such font - there are always those "security restrictions". Is there some way to do it from JavaScript (maybe even with small Flash app)?

*Update:*

Why would I need such a thing? The reason is that the app I am building works a lot like an svg editor, allowing a person to create various documents right in his browser. But I also provide facilities for PDF output and saving the edited in some intermediate format, so later the user can continue editing (possibly on another machine).

PDF carries all it's fonts right inside the file, so if user specifies some font that is only installed on his machine, I need to get that font specification and embed it into PDF file. If I get raster font representation, the quality will suffer - and since the documents are intended for printing, quality is paramount.

Same argument goes for save files - since user can transfer them to another machine with another set of fonts, I need to carry non-standard fonts inside the file.

Comment: which are you asking about, JavaScript, or Flash (which is ActionScript)? Flash has a *whole* bunch more permissions than JavaScript does, so the answers are going to be wildly different. Equally important to explain, so we don't end up with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what do you need the vectors for?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - JavaScript is preferable, but I'm willing to consider Flash-based solution as well. You are right, I'm indeed fell for XY problem - I'll update the answer with more explanations.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js

Comment: @K3N - been there, saw that. The problem is that opentype.js perfectly handles the situation once I already have the font file in my hands - but JavaScript won't allow me to do that.

Comment: @Rogach ah, my point was that you can extract path-information about a font, then use that instead of the font itself which you then embed in the document. This can be used as a substitute if the font is not available.

Comment: @K3N - yes, that's exactly what I planned to do. But how do I get to the font? I don't want to ask user to upload the .ttf manually.

Comment: In theory you can detect the system font, and then load that font from an online font repository (google webfont, typekit, etc?). Alternatively you can make your app show which fonts it can immediately use, and which would need to be uploaded by your users to their own user space (so other people can't illegally download licensed fonts) so the app can use them for generating PDFs.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - First idea is quite unreliable, but the second is quite good - I considered that. But it will require users to find and upload those fonts themselves, and I don't think my user base will be so computer literate.

Comment: they don't have to be, there are only two OSses for which you'd need to explain things, and for both Windows and OSX writing a short "hey, here's how you can find that font!" page with screenshots is pretty easy (both have fixed locations for fonts, and have "double click -> preview font" baked in so users can make double-sure they found the right one)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - yes, you are right. But still, that feels like a lot of hassle for such seemingly simple task :)

Comment: there is nothing simple about extracting data from a resource you don't have.